# Postgres function to return datetime with time zone offset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Instead of always writing:

```
select my_column at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris' from my_table;
```

I would prefer doing:

```
select dtz(my_column, 'Europe/Paris') from my_table;
```

`UTC` is system-wide (server time zone), and could even be hardcoded in `dtz()`.

Can someone share an efficient implementation of such a function?

**Edit**

```
select my_column at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris' from my_table;
```

Can be shortened a very very little bit like this:

```
select timezone('UTC', my_column) at time zone 'Europe/Paris' from my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its really dificult to see what you are having trouble with on this.

I don't believe the server timezone helps you here.  As I understand it, it's the SQL client timezone than affects this.

You're not going to get a function more efficient than (`IMMUTABLE`):

```
RETURN arg1 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE arg2;
```

But this will always be less efficient than writing it inline in your SQL.

Ideally your timestamp should be `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` instead of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` since it's being used to store absolute timestamps not local timestamps.  This would prevent the need for two conversions (into UTC and out of it).  But that does mean you would need to add the `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` into your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would use timestamp with timezone if I would manage to port Hibernate 5 to my application (yes, that way round) because the ImprovedNamingStrategy is gone and I need it. The client in my case is a Spring Boot application running on the same server than the database. For fast querying, I use the "at time zone" in SQL queries and my hope was to reduce verbosity by using a function as described in my questions. But I agree with you, using timestamp with timezone would be the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah there's no "efficient" solution more than the verbose one... the best function based one will be just a one-liner as I indicate.